# How to access (get or set) object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute

Tags: python, object, attributes

How do you set/get the values of attributes of `t` given by `x`?

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self.attr1 = 1
       self.attr2 = 2

t = Test()
x = "attr1"
```

Answer (score 509, accepted):

There are built-in functions called [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

```
getattr(object, attrname)
setattr(object, attrname, value)
```

In this case

```
x = getattr(t, 'attr1')
setattr(t, 'attr1', 21)
```

Comment: There is also delattr for deleting attributes, but this is rarely used.

Comment: and hasattr for testing whether or not an object has a specific attr though in that case using the three argument form getattr(object, attrname, default) is often better.

Comment: @ihightower See [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](/q/9437726/4518341) In short, there's no general way to do it if the scope is unknown. afult's solution assumes it's a global, though it probably is.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the logic hidden inside the class, you may prefer to use a generalized getter method like so:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 1
        self.attr2 = 2

    def get(self,varname):
        return getattr(self,varname)

t = Test()
x = "attr1"
print ("Attribute value of {0} is {1}".format(x, t.get(x)))
```

Outputs:

```
Attribute value of attr1 is 1
```

Another apporach that could hide it even better would be using the magic method `__getattribute__`, but I kept getting an endless loop which I was unable to resolve when trying to get retrieve the attribute value inside that method.

Also note that you can alternatively use `vars()`. In the above example, you could exchange `getattr(self,varname)` by `return vars(self)[varname]`, but `getattr`might be preferable according to the answer to [What is the difference between `vars` and `setattr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897575/what-is-the-difference-between-vars-and-setattr).

Answer (score 3):

#### Note: This answer is very outdated. It applies to Python 2 using the `new` module that was [deprecated in 2008](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#deprecations-and-removals).

There is python built in functions setattr and getattr. Which can used to set and get the attribute of an class.

A brief example:

```
>>> from new import  classobj

>>> obj = classobj('Test', (object,), {'attr1': int, 'attr2': int}) # Just created a class

>>> setattr(obj, 'attr1', 10)

>>> setattr(obj, 'attr2', 20)

>>> getattr(obj, 'attr1')
10

>>> getattr(obj, 'attr2')
20
```