# Can you use "first class" concept on Python methods/attributes?

Tags: python

Can the "first-class" concept be applied to Python methods/attributes like it can functions?

```
>>>a=sum
>>>a([1,2,3])
6
```

I would like to do something like:

```
>>>case='lower'
>>>'UPPERCASE'.case()
```

To produce the string object `'uppercase'`. Otherwise, would I just have to use `eval`?

Comment: Sure; `getattr('UPPERCASE', case)()` would give `'uppercase'` (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612610/3001761). Note that your examples aren't equivalent, though; in the first you assign the function itself, in the second you assign a method's *name*. More appropriate might be `case = str.lower`, then you want `case('UPPERCASE')`.

Comment: Well you certainly cannot add / change methods of string objects, if you were to subclass `str` then you could define `case = str.lower` inside the class definition, then `MyStr('UPPERCASE').case() -> 'uppercase'`

Comment: what "first-class" concept exactly means?

Comment: @mhbashari see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/705173/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
case = str.lower # Take the lower() method of the str class.
case('UPPERCASE') # pass your string as the first argument, which is self.
```

In this case, Python being explicit about `self` being the first argument to methods makes this a lot clearer to understand.