# Switch dictionary from external file by variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I'm playing with webpy and have a little problem. I cannot switch between languages. Maybe my idea is wrong. I have defined the language dictionary in an external Python file.

```
class hello:
    def GET(self, url):
        web.header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8', unique=True)
        l = accept_lang(web.ctx.env)
        if l in lg.aviable:
            return lg.hu['hello']  # < here have the problem
        else:
            return lg.en["hello"]
```

lang.py

```
aviable = ['hu','en', 'de']

hu = { "hello": 'Helló Világ' }
en = { "hello": 'Hello World' }
de = { "hello": 'Hallo Welt'  }
```

Comment: You're not actually using `l`...

Comment: How should using l ? lg.l['hello'] dont work.

Comment: Why would it, when there's no attribute named `l`? You need to use the *value* as the attribute name, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612610/3001761.

Comment: jonrsharpe thank you :)