# Use a variable with a call to a module function

Tags: python, python-3.x, simple-salesforce

I am not sure I phrased my question exactly right, but here is the code to illustrate:

```
script.py
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(login stuff here)
with open(nextObjFile, 'r') as f :
    nextObj = f.read().strip()
```

simple salesforce has a sf..describe() that I need to pass nextObj into.  Is this possible? I tried `sf.nextObj.describe()` and that does not work.

Comment: I looked at `setattr()` but I don't understand how to do it for a different module

Comment: `getattr(sf, nextObject).decribe()`?

Comment: Please add your answer, seems like getattr is working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Comment: In the future, please use the generic [python] tag for all python questions. Use a version specific tag at your discretion

Comment: Thanks for the pointers on what I was actually looking for Juanpa; I was having trouble with what the search terms were.  In addition your getattr worked.