# Reference Python function by input string

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have a Python module which has several functions in it and it should call a different function depending on user input. For example, in my code I have something like:

```
if val == "X":
    return foo.X(self)
elif val == "Y":
    return foo.Y(self)
elif val == "Z":
    return foo.Z(self)
else:
    sys.exit("ERROR: value %s DNE"%(val))
```

Is there a way to simply call the python function in `foo` module based on the input directly without multiple `if` statements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`getattr`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class Foo:
    def X(self): return 1
    def Y(self): return 2

foo = Foo()
getattr(foo, 'X')()
1
```

This works because functions are also attributes of objects. The function can then be called as normal.

But beware, you'll want to handle situations where the passed string does not match any function in `Foo`. In that case, you can use `getattr` with an optional third argument:

```
getattr(foo, 'abcd', lambda : None)()
# None
```

The lambda is returned when no attribute with that name is found.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the usual Python way to avoid the `switch` statement used in other languages: the dictionary. Functions are object, so a function can be a value in a dictionary.

```
function_dict = {'X': foo.X, 'Y': foo:Y, 'Z': foo.Z}
return function_dict[val](self)
```

If `val` is not one of the keys in the dictionary, an error will be raised. If you do not want that particular error, there are several ways to raise another error or avoid errors altogether. For example, you could use the `get` method of dictionaries to use a default value if the key is not in the dictionary. For example, if you want the method `foo.other` to be called for any key other than `X, Y, Z` you could use

```
function_dict = {'X': foo.X, 'Y': foo:Y, 'Z': foo.Z}
return function_dict.get(val, other)(self)
```

You could also check before using the dictionary if `val` is one of the keys, as in

```
function_dict = {'X': foo.X, 'Y': foo:Y, 'Z': foo.Z}
if val not in function_dict:
    sys.exit("ERROR: value %s DNE"%(val))
return function_dict[val](self)
```