# How can I update specific arguments of a class without having messy code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I'm talking about:

For example:

```py
class User():
    def __init__(self, username, fullname):
        self.username = username
        self.fullname = fullname

    def update(self, arg, value):
        if arg is 'username':
            self.username = value
        elif arg is 'fullname':
            self.fullname = value
```

In the update function I am letting the user input a param they want to update, `arg`, with the value specified, `value`.

If I ever wanted to add more args to the `User` class, I would need to change the update function as well with the added arguments. How can I create a dynamic update function that accepts any of the existing arguments in the class `__init__`?

Ex: If I added `email` arg to `__init__()`, I would need to add this to the `update()` function:

```py
if arg is 'email':
    self.email = value
```

^ this would get annoying after a while.

I hope you understand what I'm asking. If you need any more clarification let me know

Comment: There's a builtin function that already does this, it's called setattr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Comment: `setattr(self, arg, value)` would work any param in `update()` method.

Comment: Why do you need this? What is stopping you from setting the attributes? Like `x.username = blah` instead of `x.update('username', blah)`? If `username` is a string naming a variable, so `setattr(x , 'username', blah)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to generalise your  update function, like this:

```
def update(self, arg, value):
    setattr(self, arg, value)
```

Then...

```
>>> john = User('teraspora', 'John Lynch')
>>> john.username
'teraspora'
>>> john.update('username', 'Aladdin')
>>> john.username
'Aladdin'
```

Hope this helps!