# How to Access Class methods using strings

Tags: python, string, class

```
class A:

   def f1(a,b):
       return a+b

   def f2(a,b):
       return a*b

   def f3(a,b):
       return a-b

obj = A()
string = 'f1'
```

I need to access method f1 using the string. 
Something like :

```
obj.string(a,b)
```

How can I achieve this ??
**getattr(obj, ' f1 ')** does not send any parameters a,b to the funct.
Converting string into an object, is not helping. I even tried function mapping, but that too caused errors.

Comment: [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr) does that. i.e. `getattr(obj, "f1")`.

Comment: Why do you have a method name in a string in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Comment: How to send the parameters a,b along ??

Comment: @Addi `getattr(obj, "f1")(a, b)` except... your methods should be static-/class-methods.