# Combine command with variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a basic question about how Python(3) works.

I have a python script which I run with an argument. This argument can have a lot of different values.

This looks as follows: `python script.py argument`

Inside the script I have a command that looks as follows: `command.a(some parameters)`.

Right now if I want to run `command.b(some parameters)` or `command.d(some parameters)` I need to go to the script, change the `command.a` to `command.b` or `command.d`.

I want my script to be more flexible so if I run `python script.py argument` that inside the script `command.argument(some parameters)` gets executed and I no longer need to change the value myself before running it.

How would one achieve this in Python? I'm not sure if I explained this clearly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on it a bit more using proper examples?

Comment: @MayankPorwal I tried to rephrase my question. Hope it is a little more clear.

Comment: @Stuffooh I've added an answer. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Have you already written code that takes a command line argument? If so your question just boils down to how to use that argument to run a function/method of the same name within your code. Correct?

Comment: @ThaerA I have edited my question in hope to clarify it. I am not very comfortable yet with python terminology.

Comment: @SimonN I have edited my question in hope to clarify it. I am not very comfortable yet with python terminology.

Comment: @Stuffooh Can you share your code so far?

Comment: That was a pretty major edit. I'm not sure the new version is similar enough to the original to actually be a new version rather than a whole new question - at first, I thought you were abusing the edit system to bypass rate limits and ask a new, entirely unrelated question.

Comment: Anyway, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib

Comment: @ThaerA the code consist out of a few thousand lines spread over multiple scripts not sure how to post the code in a clear way.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm sorry I did not mean to abuse the system or break any rules. I'm new to both Python and stackoverflow so struggled writing my question down properly for other people to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't understand your question :D
For this case you can use an input to specify what do you need:

type=int(input("What Type Of Def You Want To Use?  "))

And then you can put an IF for you selection:

if(type==1):
    command.a(args)

elif(type==2):
    command.b(args)

elif(type==3):
    command.c(args)

else:
    print("Invalid Command.. Use:[1,2,3]")

Hope it works for you this time :D

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use your if statement structure to solve my problem. It is not ideal but don't see any other way to fix it.

Comment: Np. I just wanted to say it in a simple way. U can use ur creativity for my case too like put it in a (while) or etc.Also you can use input keyboard instead of a variable.. like when u click (A) on ur keyboard.. the program will notice ur option.. Just tried to do my best and hope helped. Sorry again for the first answer :D

Answer (score -1):

You can use `input`:

```
name = input ("What's your name")
print ("Hello, ", name )
```

If you're writing a command line tool, it's very doable with the [click package](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/). See their Hello World example:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

Running `python hello.py --count=3` will give you the output below:

```
Your name: John
Hello John!
Hello John!
Hello John!
```