# How to refer to an object properties if I have the object name as string

Tags: python, object

I'm using Python (the latest one with PyQt5)
In my screen I have 30 labels and their names are label_01 to label_30.
I want to change the text of several labels based on some logic.

The labels that I want to change are kept in a list of strings (names of the labels)
For instance lets assume the my logic selected these labels: label_13, label_16, label_28

**The question**
Since the list of the labels is dynamic, how can I change the labels in loop that based on the list?

I can do this:  self.label_1.setText('Command sent..')
But how can I pass the label name as parameter instead of "label_1"

Thank you
Eyal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: setattr is your friend (setattr(self, label_name, value))

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612615/12693728) ?

Comment: Use a list for your labels. Or even better: give them useful names and use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setattr` which receives 3 params: the object whose attribute has to be set (can be `self` if used inside of class definition), the name of the attribute as a string and the new value.

Try:

```
# let `labels_to_change` be your dynamic list of labels you want to change and set them to be equal to new_value
labels_to_change = ['label_1','label_3']
new_value = "new_value"

for label in labels_to_change:
    setattr(getattr(self, label), "text", new_value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gabip 

In your example where is the label property like: text 
do i have to code 
labels_to_change = ['label_1.text','label_3.text']
?
Thanks!

Comment: @EyalTal, `labels_to_change` is just an example for your dynamic list of labels to change. Just use the `for` loop and replace `labels_to_change` with your actual list of labels to be changed.

Comment: I understand that,  but where is the place that I have to put the attribute that i need to change for instance the .text :
object.text = 'xxx'

Comment: @EyalTal it should be the second param of `setattr` function. In my solution I assumed that you want to iterate over dynamic list of attributes and set a new value for them so in my post, `label` equals to the attribute name you want to set. If you just want to set it once, use `setattr(object_name, attribute_name, new_value)`

Comment: That's the code but it is not change the label text

labels_to_change = ['label_1.text', 'label_2.text']
                    new_value = "new_value"
                    for label in labels_to_change:
                        setattr(self, label, new_value)

what is wrong here?

Comment: The first line is working but not the second.
self.label_1.setText('Command sent,')
setattr(self, 'label_2.setText', 'new_value')

Comment: Ok, you had to mention that you want to update an attribute inside another attribute. I've updated the answer. Try now please...

Comment: Gabi - still nothing changed.

'code'
 def docmd(self):
        labels_to_change = ['label_1', 'label_2']
        new_value = "new_value"
        for label in labels_to_change:
            setattr(getattr(self, label), "text", new_value)

Comment: Could you please edit your question with your code?

Comment: The problematic section is : def startBackup(self):

Comment: The code run with no issue but the labels are not changed.