# Print all the values of an object as listed in dir() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The dir() function returns the list of all the returns, all properties and methods of a specific object, without any values.

How to return the values? I try to loop through the list, without success.

As an example, I tried to loop as such:

```
for attr in dir(results1):
    print(results1.attr)
```

Comment: try: `print(attr)` or `print(dir(results1))`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib

Comment: Did you try `print(attr)` instead of `print(results1.attr)`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for attr in dir(results1):
    print(getattr(results1,attr))
```

You need to use `getattr` since `attr` is a string rather than a literal attribute name.