# How to access class attribute using variable value in Flask python?

Tags: python, flask

I have a form class like

```
class StudentForm(FlaskForm):
      bool_1= BooleanField('Set bool_1')
      bool_2= BooleanField('Set bool_2')
```

Now in view, I want to get the value of fields like

```
@app.route('/student', methods=['POST'])
def student():
    fields = ['bool_1', 'bool_2']
    form = StudentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       for field in fields:
         if form.field.data is True:
           print('OK')
    return render_template('abc.html', form=form)
```

But it showing `'StudentForm' object has no attribute 'field'`, I know the `field` is a `string`. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664376/5516057. And maybe read through something like this: https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-working-with-forms. It seems strange to me that you instantiate a new `StudentForm()` when you are handling a post request. You want to see the data that comes out of the request I'm guessing? What I think you want to do looks more like this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/student', methods=['POST'])
def student():
    fields = ['bool_1', 'bool_2']
    form = request.form # request is a flask thing that handles the data from the request

    for field in fields:
       if form.get(field) is True: # use get, if the strings defined in fields are not in the form in the request this returns None like a normal dict I think
           print('OK')
    return render_template('abc.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
@app.route('/student', methods=['POST'])
def student():
    form = StudentForm()
    for k, v in form.data.items():
        if v:
            print('OK')
    return render_template('abc.html', form=form)
```

And there is no need to check the `request.method` because you have restricted `methods` to only be `POST` in the `route` decorator.