# Concatenating variable with "self" in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have 10 check-boxes and to check whether the checkbox is checked or not, I was trying to use loop. `tacb1` is the name of the 1st checkbox, `tacb2` is the name of 2nd checkbox and so on. I want to use a loop which looks something like:

```
    for i in range(1,11):                        
        if self.tacb'"+i+"'isChecked() == True:
            print("hi")  
        else:
            print("bye")
```

It is throwing the error for the line `self.tacb'"+i+"'isChecked()` as invalid syntax. How to concatenate a variable with `self`?

Comment: You cannot concatenate object references and strings. Use `getattr(self, 'tacb{}'.format(i)).isChecked()`. See [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlexLaur's answer using lists is the best way to do this but in the interest of completeness, here is an example of how you would use `getattr` to do the same thing

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.item1 = 1
        self.item2 = 2
        self.item3 = 3

    def check(self):
        for i in range(1,4):
            print(getattr(self,f'item{i}'))

c = MyClass()
c.check()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to store all checkboxs instance into a list like that :

```
self.all_checkboxs = [checkox_a, checkox_b, ..., checkox_n]
```

And then you can iterate through like this:

```
for checkbox in self.all_checkboxs:
    if checkbox.isChecked():
        bar()
    else:
        foo()
```

If you really need to use strings, you can use python exec(), but I not recommend this way.

Comment: It is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why suggest `exec`, when one can (and *should*) just use `getattr`?

Comment: You are right @musicamante. I didn't think about this way when I posted my answer. But using getattr is better than the exec().