# How to load a Class from File given only its String specification in Python?

Tags: python, class, import

I intend to let a user decide during runtime (in my Python 3.8 program) which class from a given set of classes to load for executing some actions.
For example, if we were talking about food, the user could decide whether to go for `eggs` or `sausage`. Both these classes are defined in one or multiple separate file(s), (both of which are) contained in a known folder.

Now, my question is how to load the corresponding class `eggs` given the string representation `eggs` (entered by a user). I saw that a method `__import__` exists which is meant to solve exactly such issues. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__), one could get access to class `eggs` defined in `spam.ham` by executing:

```
_temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], -1)
eggs = _temp.eggs
```

which is equivalent to `from spam.ham import eggs`.

The problem with this example is that it assumes the code snippet `_temp.eggs`, which is not given/known a priori in my case.
Therefore, I would like to know how to transform `eggs = _temp.eggs` into some statement where `_temp.eggs` is replaced by some statement where `.eggs` is replaced by some string representation of `eggs`.

For example, given `_temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], -1)`, I am looking for some command like `eggs = _temp['eggs']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, given the starting point:

```
_temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], -1)
```

the problem eventually boils down to that of retrieving an object's attribute by the attribute's name.

The answer to that problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612615/11478452).

Hence, given `_temp`, class `eggs` can be accessed by `eggs = getattr(_temp, 'eggs')`.