# Returning True if a value is present in an enum; returning false if not

Tags: python, enums

I apologise if I'm missing anything obvious; is there a way to see if a value is in an enum which returns True if it is, False if not? For example, if I take the following enum from the python documentation,

```py
from enum import Enum
class Colour(Enum):
     RED = 1
     GREEN = 2
     BLUE = 3
```

is there any way to do the following action, or an equivalent, without an exception being raised:

```py
colour_test = "YELLOW"
if Colour[colour_test]:
    print("In enum")
else:
    print("Not in enum")
## Output wanted - "Not in enum"
## Actual output - KeyError: "YELLOW"
```

I know that I can use try;except statements, but I'd prefer not to in this situation as I'd like to use this conditional with some others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Comment: @KaiserKatze yes, the getattr() method works for what I'm doing - I personally find the `x in y.__members__` dictionary solution more elegant to use though, which is what I'm now implementing over getattr()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enums have a `__members__` dict that you can check:

```py
if colour_test in Colour.__members__:
    print("In enum")
else:
    print("Not in enum")
```

You can alternatively use a generalized approach with `hasattr`, but this returns wrong results for some non-members like `"__new__"`:

```py
if hasattr(Colour, colour_test):
    print("In enum")
else:
    print("Not in enum")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if colour_test in Colour.__members__:
    print("In enum")
else:
    print("Not in enum")
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do is add try.. except block where except block will catch the KeyError.

```
    colour_test = "YELLOW"
    try:
         if Colour[colour_test]:
             print("In enum")
    except KeyError:
        print("Not in enum")
```

Comment: "I know that I can use try;except statements, but I'd prefer not to in this situation as I'd like to use this conditional with some others."

Comment: @Aplet123 so you package this into a simple function you can call from anywhere, that returns `True` or `False`.  What's the problem?

Comment: @MarkRansom. The problem is that it does not meet the clear spec

Answer (score 1):

If the Enums in question are yours, add a function to them:

```
from enum import Enum

class CustomEnum(Enum):
    #
    @classmethod
    def has_enum(cls, name):
        return name in cls.__members__

class Color(CustomEnum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2
    GREEN = 3
```

and in use:

```
>>> Color.has_enum('RED')
True
```

If you want to be able to do this with Enums outside your control, extract the `has_enum` function above:

```
def has_enum(cls, name):
    return name in cls.__members__
```

and use that:

```
>>> has_enum(Color, 'GREEN')
True
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 0):

`getattr` with the default argument would probably be the easiest way:

```
gotten = getattr(Colour, "GREEN", None)

if gotten is None:
    # Not in the enum
else:
    # gotten is in the enum
```

`gotten` will be `None` (or whatever you put as the third argument to `getattr`) if it doesn't exist.

Or, with `:=` to make it a little more succint:

```
if gotten := getattr(Colour, "GREEN", None):
    # The string is in the enum
else:
    # Not in the enum
```

---

@Aplet's suggestion of `hasattr` is likely more appropriate here in retrospect. I like `getattr` with a `None` third argument because a lot of the time, if I'm checking if something has an attribute, I also want to use that attribute after the check. Use `hasattr` if you only care about whether or not it's there, but `getattr` is nice if you also want to use the value post-lookup.