# I need help using variables to reference function in a class

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have some code that I want to work. So basically I have multiple classes and multiple functions in those classes. The user inputs the name of the class and the function inside it but I don't know how to make it work.

This is my code:

```
Class = #The Users Input
Function = #The users Input

Class.Function # So I want to reference the function with the users input
```

I get a syntax error.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612610/3001761

Comment: What is your syntax error?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: `getattr(locals()["object"], "method")()` where `object` is the name of the object (not class) and `method` is the name of the method associated with the object.

Comment: Please add exact code and error message.

Answer (score 1):

**Creating the classes:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        #this function will be called everytime whenever the class is called
    def func1(self):
        #first function
    def func2(self):
        #second function

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        #this function will be called everytime whenever the class is called
    def func1(self):
        #first function
    def func2(self):
        #second function
```

**Calling the classes:**

```
try1=A()
try2=B()

#calling function1 of the first class
a=try1.func1()
```