# How to use a different function at each iteration

Tags: python, function, methods

Instead of writing the same line for each function (as shown in the first code block), I want to call each function with the help of a loop (as shown in the 2nd code block)

What I want to be able to do is:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
B = np.array([3,4,6,3,2,7,0,1,7]).reshape(3,3)
#################

def calc_stats(mat):
    print(mat.max())
    print(mat.min())
    print(mat.mean())

calc_stats(A)
calc_stats(B)
```

But by the use of a **loop** where at each iteration I can change the name of the function.
Something similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
B = np.array([3,4,6,3,2,7,0,1,7]).reshape(3,3)
#################

def calc_stats(mat):
    for names in ["mean", "max", "min"]:
        print(mat.names())

calc_stats(A)
calc_stats(B)
```

Of course, the above code doesn't work because a variable cannot be used as a function name, but is there any method to implement what I want to do?

---

This question got closed the last time I posted it because it seemed similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib), but I'm finding the answers provided in this post a bit hard to understand or relate to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use strings for the names you can obtain the functions using getattr():

```
def calc_stats(mat):
    for name in ["mean", "max", "min"]:
        print(getattr(np,name)(mat))
```

output:

```
calc_stats(A)
4.0
8
0

calc_stats(B)
3.6666666666666665
7
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a list of functions to call, the call each one on the provided argument

```
def calc_stats(mat):
    for f in [np.mean, np.max, np.min]:
        print(f(mat))
```

Output

```
>>> calc_stats(A)
4.0
8
0
>>> calc_stats(B)
3.6666666666666665
7
0
```

Comment: Won't this become very specific, then? I won't be able to use it for variables other than A, I think.

Comment: @ray_lv Then use a function
def all_functions(b):
    for f in [b.mean, b.max, b.min]:
           print(f())

Comment: @ray_lv If this is not general enough for your use case can you edit your question with an  more specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I've made some edits for more clarification about how I should be able to use different variables as well.

Comment: @ray_lv I've edited my answer, is this closer to what you're looking for?