# Looping through objects in a list and appending them to other objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through a list of variables but I'm unable to access the variable when I append it with `self`

```
var_list = [account, user, authenticator, database, schema, warehouse, role]

for var in var_list:
    if var == None:
        var = self.var  # <---- the .var here is not taking the var from var_list
    else: 
        var
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `self` in this case?  Why do you think that `self.var` should take values from `var_list`?  What is the lone `var` in the `else` branch meant to do?

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-in-a/0596001886/ch04s03.html

Comment: @0x5453 good question, This loop resides within a class's method. So the self is just the variables set in the __init__ function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Comment: Are you trying to automate `account = self.account; user = self.user; # etc`?

Comment: @chepner if the variables are not inputted into a method of a class, use the variables that were used in the `__init__`  function of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to update the value of a variable given its name as a string. I would just bite the bullet and write a series of `if` statements.

```
if account is None:
    account = self.account

if user is None:
    user = self.user

# etc
```

Note that I do *not* consider using `exec` to execute a dynamically constructed assignment statement a good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very clear, but it looks like you want to get, in order

- `self.account`
- `self.user`
- `self.authenticator`
- etc

You can do this using the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```py
var_list = ["account", "user", "authenticator", "database", "schema", "warehouse", "role"]

for var in var_list:
        var_value = getattr(self, var)
```

Answer (score 0):

RoadieRich is correct, though you should be careful using getattr/setattr too much when you can avoid it. (For instance, if your user could get control of var_list, they could get access to any attributes they wanted.)

If you just want to access the values of these attributes:

```
var_list = [self.account, self.user, self.authenticator, 
            self.database, self.schema, self.warehouse, self.role]
```

---

For a simple look at why this happens: Intuitively, python has a mapping of variable names to values. (many mappings, in reality, but let's ignore that for simplicity. You can read [this post](http://oreilly.com/library/view/python-in-a/0596001886/ch04s03.html) for a bit more info). That mapping might look like:

```
account =>> 1234
user =>> User class @ 0x0340 [A reference to a User class at some random place in memory]
...
```

When you run `var_list = [account, user]`, it does something like

```
account =>> 1234
user =>> User class @ 0x0340
var_list =>> List class @ 0x0350 <list_0>
list_0<element 0> =>> 1234
list_0<element 1> =>> User class @ 0x0340
...
```

See that the elements of the list only know their values, not what they were called.

If your mapping instead looks like:

```
self =>> YourClass @ 0x0340 <your_class_0>
your_class_0<account> =>> 1234
your_class_0<user> =>> User class @ 0x0350
...
```

Then trying to do `var_list = [account, user]` will cause an error, because there isn't anything called `account` in the mapping table.