# Is there a way to access just the value of object attribute when calling it as a variable

Tags: python

Is there a way to access the value of a variable without taking the variables name?
I am trying to write a project which has an external constants file for colour definitions which I will use in the various programs to de-clutter my code.

The colours are set as RGB with the colour name such as:

```
BLACK = (0,0,0)
```

An example of the class which will use the colour is:

```
class Window:

    def __init__(self,w_width,w_height,w_colour,fps=60):
        pygame.init()
        self.w_width = w_width
        self.w_height = w_height
        self.fps = fps
        self.w_colour = w_colour
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w_width,self.w_height))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.screen.fill(constants.self.w_colour)
```

And am coming into the error where `constants.self.w_colour` doesn't exist (which I understand as i'm assuming it is looking for a `self.w_colour` within the `constants` file which I know doesn't exist).  But the value of `self.w_colour` could be `BLACK` or some other value which I know is contained in the `constants` file.
I was wondering if there is a way to call the `constants.self.w_colour` by taking the value of `self.w_colour` and not python trying to follow it as a path?

Apologies if it doesn't make much sense but i've tried to describe it in the best way I can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Comment: put them in a `dict`, instead of as free-floating constant variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're throwing all of your constants in a file called `constants.py` somewhere. If so, the quick-and-dirty solution is to use `__dict__`.

```
import constants

my_favorite_color = constants.__dict__[color_name]
```

but that's messy and would confuse folks reading the code. If you *intend* that `constants` be accessed as a dictionary, then it would be best to make that explicit. In `constants.py`, consider

```
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
# ... more colors

# Then at the bottom
COLORS = {
  'BLACK': BLACK,
  'WHITE': WHITE,
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
from constants import COLORS

my_favorite_color = COLORS[color_name]
```

It's a bit more verbose, but [in the words of a wise man](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: Is there no way of keeping it out of a dictionary, Im not all that familiar with them thats all

Comment: There is not. Even the first "hack" solution I proposed is using a dictionary. It's just using an implicit one generated by the system. It's probably best to familiarize yourself with data structures sooner rather than later. Lists and dictionaries are not going to go away as you write more Python code.