# How to convert string to attribute name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

I am using win32api to get keystates.I used win32con.VK... buttons from virtual keyboard and check all of the keys using loop but the problem is that i read from a file which stores virtual keycodes and reading from file will give string

I want to write like say

```
win32con.VK_OEM_8
```

but reading from file will give

```
win32con.'VK_OEM_8'.
```

I want to remove these '' to get win32con to work

Any Idea?

Comment: Naive answer is that you call `getattr`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Comment: Already Tried that but you can't do it right here since we don't have the instance of Class to use `getattr` and the link was talking about the instance of class

Comment: In other words,  win32con contains all variable like you can say that we are importing variables from win32con, so how can we write like win32con.VK_LEFT we can't do this one by one this takes a lot of time

Comment: This is not the duplicate so kindly remove the downvote @Jeaninez-MSFT
Thanks!

Comment: @OldGamingisGoldGaming I just suggest you could refer to the thread, and I didn't vote for the downvote.

Comment: Can you please guide me I am new don't know about threading or edit my question i hope you understand what i want

Answer (score -1):

In this particular case I use the dictionary method since I got every value.

First I get all keys code and values from original MS website then I paste the file in txt file and opened it in python file and make a python file with dictionary keys as keycodes and values as value of keys then I copied the dictionary to my actual program.

Here,  are the results

```
codes = {'VK_BACK': 0x08, 'VK_TAB': 0x09, 'VK_CLEAR': 0x0C, 'VK_RETURN': 0x0D, 'VK_SHIFT': 0x10, 'VK_CONTROL': 0x11,
     'VK_MENU': 0x12, 'VK_PAUSE': 0x13, 'VK_CAPITAL': 0x14, 'VK_KANA': 0x15, 'VK_HANGUEL': 0x15, 'VK_HANGUL': 0x15,
     'VK_IME_ON': 0x16, 'VK_JUNJA': 0x17, 'VK_FINAL': 0x18, 'VK_HANJA': 0x19, 'VK_KANJI': 0x19, 'VK_IME_OFF': 0x1A,
     'VK_ESCAPE': 0x1B, 'VK_CONVERT': 0x1C, 'VK_NONCONVERT': 0x1D, 'VK_ACCEPT': 0x1E, 'VK_MODECHANGE': 0x1F,
     'VK_SPACE': 0x20, 'VK_PRIOR': 0x21, 'VK_NEXT': 0x22, 'VK_END': 0x23, 'VK_HOME': 0x24, 'VK_LEFT': 0x25,
     'VK_UP': 0x26, 'VK_RIGHT': 0x27, 'VK_DOWN': 0x28, 'VK_SELECT': 0x29, 'VK_PRINT': 0x2A, 'VK_EXECUTE': 0x2B,
     'VK_SNAPSHOT': 0x2C, 'VK_INSERT': 0x2D, 'VK_DELETE': 0x2E, 'VK_HELP': 0x2F, 'VK_0': 0x30, 'VK_1': 0x31,
     'VK_2': 0x32, 'VK_3': 0x33, 'VK_4': 0x34, 'VK_5': 0x35, 'VK_6': 0x36, 'VK_7': 0x37, 'VK_8': 0x38, 'VK_9': 0x39,
     'VK_A': 0x41, 'VK_B': 0x42, 'VK_C': 0x43, 'VK_D': 0x44, 'VK_E': 0x45, 'VK_F': 0x46, 'VK_G': 0x47, 'VK_H': 0x48,
     'VK_I': 0x49, 'VK_J': 0x4A, 'VK_K': 0x4B, 'VK_L': 0x4C, 'VK_M': 0x4D, 'VK_N': 0x4E, 'VK_O': 0x4F, 'VK_P': 0x50,
     'VK_Q': 0x51, 'VK_R': 0x52, 'VK_S': 0x53, 'VK_T': 0x54, 'VK_U': 0x55, 'VK_V': 0x56, 'VK_W': 0x57, 'VK_X': 0x58,
     'VK_Y': 0x59, 'VK_Z': 0x5A, 'VK_LWIN': 0x5B, 'VK_RWIN': 0x5C, 'VK_APPS': 0x5D, 'VK_SLEEP': 0x5F,
     'VK_NUMPAD0': 0x60, 'VK_NUMPAD1': 0x61, 'VK_NUMPAD2': 0x62, 'VK_NUMPAD3': 0x63, 'VK_NUMPAD4': 0x64,
     'VK_NUMPAD5': 0x65, 'VK_NUMPAD6': 0x66, 'VK_NUMPAD7': 0x67, 'VK_NUMPAD8': 0x68, 'VK_NUMPAD9': 0x69,
     'VK_MULTIPLY': 0x6A, 'VK_ADD': 0x6B, 'VK_SEPARATOR': 0x6C, 'VK_SUBTRACT': 0x6D, 'VK_DECIMAL': 0x6E,
     'VK_DIVIDE': 0x6F, 'VK_F1': 0x70, 'VK_F2': 0x71, 'VK_F3': 0x72, 'VK_F4': 0x73, 'VK_F5': 0x74, 'VK_F6': 0x75,
     'VK_F7': 0x76, 'VK_F8': 0x77, 'VK_F9': 0x78, 'VK_F10': 0x79, 'VK_F11': 0x7A, 'VK_F12': 0x7B, 'VK_F13': 0x7C,
     'VK_F14': 0x7D, 'VK_F15': 0x7E, 'VK_F16': 0x7F, 'VK_F17': 0x80, 'VK_F18': 0x81, 'VK_F19': 0x82, 'VK_F20': 0x83,
     'VK_F21': 0x84, 'VK_F22': 0x85, 'VK_F23': 0x86, 'VK_F24': 0x87, 'VK_NUMLOCK': 0x90, 'VK_SCROLL': 0x91,
     'VK_LSHIFT': 0xA0, 'VK_RSHIFT': 0xA1, 'VK_LCONTROL': 0xA2, 'VK_RCONTROL': 0xA3, 'VK_LMENU': 0xA4,
     'VK_RMENU': 0xA5, 'VK_BROWSER_BACK': 0xA6, 'VK_BROWSER_FORWARD': 0xA7, 'VK_BROWSER_REFRESH': 0xA8,
     'VK_BROWSER_STOP': 0xA9, 'VK_BROWSER_SEARCH': 0xAA, 'VK_BROWSER_FAVORITES': 0xAB, 'VK_BROWSER_HOME': 0xAC,
     'VK_VOLUME_MUTE': 0xAD, 'VK_VOLUME_DOWN': 0xAE, 'VK_VOLUME_UP': 0xAF, 'VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK': 0xB0,
     'VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK': 0xB1, 'VK_MEDIA_STOP': 0xB2, 'VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE': 0xB3, 'VK_LAUNCH_MAIL': 0xB4,
     'VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT': 0xB5, 'VK_LAUNCH_APP1': 0xB6, 'VK_LAUNCH_APP2': 0xB7, 'VK_OEM_1': 0xBA,
     'VK_OEM_PLUS': 0xBB, 'VK_OEM_COMMA': 0xBC, 'VK_OEM_MINUS': 0xBD, 'VK_OEM_PERIOD': 0xBE, 'VK_OEM_2': 0xBF,
     'VK_OEM_3': 0xC0, 'VK_OEM_4': 0xDB, 'VK_OEM_5': 0xDC, 'VK_OEM_6': 0xDD, 'VK_OEM_7': 0xDE, 'VK_OEM_8': 0xDF,
     '0xE1': 0xE1, 'VK_OEM_102': 0xE2, 'VK_PROCESSKEY': 0xE5, '0xE6': 0xE6, 'VK_ATTN': 0xF6, 'VK_CRSEL': 0xF7,
     'VK_EXSEL': 0xF8, 'VK_EREOF': 0xF9, 'VK_PLAY': 0xFA, 'VK_ZOOM': 0xFB, 'VK_NONAME': 0xFC, 'VK_PA1': 0xFD,
     'VK_OEM_CLEAR': 0xFE, }
```

Now instead of calling win32con.VK_BACK you can call

```
win32api.Getkeystate(codes["VK_BACK"])
```

Thanks!