# How to give a parameter to a function that uses it as an attribute of a class

Tags: python

Let's say that I have a class:

```
class Hello():
    who = {they, you}
    how = {good, bad}
```

And with a function parameter I want to specify which attribute I want to see.

```
def choose(who_or_how):
    print(Hello.who_or_how)
```

Is there a way for doing it?

Comment: You could use e.g. `getattr(Hello, 'who')`.  But that is sometimes a code smell - instead it may be better to put `who` and `how` into a `dict`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib