# Assigning values to variables using for loop

Tags: python, class, for-loop, global

I want to create variables that hold the values packet.{name of the variable}.
For example, I want sectID to get the value of packet.sectID.
I've tried:

```
lst = ['sectID','MP_Sector_ID']
for field in lst:
    globals()[field]=packet.field
```

but packet.field doesn't give me the right value.
Also packet is a class.

Comment: What language are you writing in? Might be useful to add this to the question or as a tag

Comment: [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612610)

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve....   are you trying to assign `list` items to a `dict` ?

Comment: for field in lst_duplicates:
            globals()[field] = getattr(packet, field)
That worked, thank you @JohnnyMopp

Comment: There is no dict, I'm trying to assign values to new variables. @D.L

Comment: are the items in the list the variable `names` or their `values` of both ?

Comment: variables names

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['sectID','MP_Sector_ID']
for field in lst_duplicates: 
    globals()[field] = getattr(packet, field)
```