# SQLAlchemy multi query filter from list

Tags: filter, sqlalchemy

I try to make a multi column filter from a list:

if I print the list a I have this:

```
['Cms.name.like(v)']
```

the code used :

```
 # columns filter
    filters = list()
    i = 0

    while True:
        col_value = request.args.get(f'columns[{i}][search][value]')
        if col_value is None:
            break
        col_name = request.args.get(f'columns[{i}][data]')
        col_value = request.args.get(f'columns[{i}][search][value]')
        if col_value:
            filters.append("Cms." + col_name + ".like(" + col_value + ")")
        i += 1

    if filters:
        for f in filters:
            print(f)
            query = query.filter(f)
```

so normally I guess to have something like:

```
query = query.filter(Cms.name.like('value'))
```

but the error is :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual SQL expression 'Cms.name.like(v)' should be explicitly declared as text('Cms.name.like(v)')
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access (get or set) object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-get-or-set-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-o)

Comment: SQLAlchemy filters are objects, not strings. You need to use `getattr`  do what you are trying to do, for example `filter_ = getattr(Cms, 'col_name').ilike(value)`

Comment: thx a lot it's working :D